# Distribution of a chrome app from outside Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome-app

I can not find any info about possibility to host chrome app on my web site and provide it for user to download, avoiding google chrome store. Is it possible?

---

When I double click on downloaded extension it says "Apps, extensions, and user scripts cannot be added from this website", however I see some installed extensions have a notice that it was installed from outside Chrome Web Store. So maybe it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [can't do that anymore with *extensions*](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/05/continuing-to-protect-chrome-users-from.html), but every announcement Google has done about was specifically about extensions. Apps are a different beast.

[In the very first one](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html) they specifically mentioned:

> Chrome Apps will also continue to be supported normally

Unless that changed unannounced, you should be able to [host your app](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting), including autoupdate, on your own website. The "drag the .crx" flow still works, also because apps are not restricted.

**Update:** Looks like as a collateral you can't initiate an install normally even for apps, because of the "Apps, extensions, and user scripts cannot be added from this website" error. I do believe Chrome still won't disable apps installed with the dragging way.

However, you should also consider using [inline install](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation); it's minimally disruptive as far as flow goes for your users.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extensions are just `.crx` files, so you should be able to just point them to a `.crx` file and tell them to drag it into their Extensions page.

Although, I think I heard a while back that after an update Chrome prevented users from installing `.crx` extensions into Chrome directly, so you may also have to address that in your instructions.

**In summary:** you have to download the `.crx` file locally and drag it into `chrome://extensions` for this to work.

Comment: When I double click on downloaded extension it says "Apps, extensions, and user scripts cannot be added from this website", however I see some installed extensions have a notice that it was installed from outside Chrome Web Store

Comment: @ZuzEL Might be wrong, but I believe you have to download locally first before doing that.

Comment: Ok, you are right. I should drag it to extensions page. Please edit your answer so it would be clear that only by dragging you can install it.

Comment: Won't work anymore for extensions, and the question isn't about extensions.